# 1. Можно ли через консоль изменить программы по умолчанию? 2. Можно как-то в cmd узнать папку для программ по умолчанию?

Tags: windows, cmd

1. Можно ли через консоль изменить программы по умолчанию?

Например чтобы .mp3 всегда открывался через aimp3

2. Можно как-то в cmd узнать папку для программ по умолчанию?

На пример С:\Program Files

Comment: 1) Да, импортировать в реестр соотв. .REG-файл; 2) Да, посмотреть значение системной переменной ProgramFiles.

Comment: а где хранятся в реестре программы по умолчанию?

Comment: В HKCR. А вот там возможны несколько альтернативных вариантов организации ассоциации типа с приложением.

Comment: а как сделать чтобы тип открывался от конкретного exe файла? просто в реестре везде указан тип, а через что открывать нет.

Comment: *в реестре везде указан тип* Ну теперь смотри раздел с этим типом - там будет, чем открывать... или ссылка на постоянный обработчик.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для ассоциации типа файла и программы необходимо использовать 2 команды: [`assoc`](https://ss64.com/nt/assoc.html) и [`ftype`](https://ss64.com/nt/ftype.html).

Пример ассоциации нового расширения с именем типа:

`assoc .NewExtension = NewTypeName` (для удаления ассоциации просто `assoc .NewExtension=`)

Пример задания программы для открытия файлов нового типа:

`ftype NewTypeName = [FilePath]` (для удаления ассоциации `ftype NewTypeName=`)

---

Для просмотра текущей папки для установки приложении посмотрите значение системной переменной `ProgramFiles`.

На 64-разрадной машине из 64-разрядного приложения:

```
echo %programfiles%
echo %programfiles(x86)%

Output:
C:\Program Files
C:\Program Files (x86)
```

На 64-разрядной машине из 32-разрядного приложения:

```
echo %programfiles%
echo %programfiles(x86)%

Output:
Program Files (x86)
C:\Program Files (x86)
```